# What's the better integration strategy for Dynamics CRM

Tags: architecture, dynamics-crm, integration

I'll try to be as specific as possible with what I need
Background : I am a software developer and I try to do all sorts of things as much as I can. I have recently gone "Mission Impossible" and accepted the to implement a Microsoft Dynamics CRM project for a client that I did some .Net web development for.

Basically, they have a web application front end/CMS membership website and they want to use Dynamics CRM to manage their members, contacts, etc.

I am trying to decide how best to implement this.

1. I can have both systems run their data in parallel and develop some kind of middleware which would use a pub/sub mechanism to synchronise the data between both systems. (this is my preference as I think it is more fault tolerant)
2. I can have the CMS directly read and write to/from Dynamics using one of the various extensibility mechanisms in dynamics (read web services). I would then write plugins (I guess) to update any tables within the CMS system from dynamics if required. I'm not a particular fan of this method though it is probably the easier of the two to implement.

My question then is

1. What kinds of integration patterns are others using out there in the wild wild jungle
2. Am I being paranoid about option 2?
3. If I went with option 1, what technologies would I be best to use, queues (msmq, rabbitmq...etc), simple database tables..., windows services for polling, Biztalk (never used that one before).

I guess rather than lead on responses, I would just appreciate if people who are knowledgeable offer some kind of guidance. I am happy to answer any specific questions to shed more light. Thanks in advance.